# What would be considered too long on a web session timeout?

Tags: session, grails

The default setting on an application I am working on was 30 mins.  I would like to increase to an hour and half, 2 hours.  What are the drawbacks for doing this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What sort of a web session are we talking about here? Is it over SSL? What is the app doing or waiting for? Incomplete data will have incomplete answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue would be memory, but it's not necessarily a significant one. With a long timeout if you have a lot of sessions and a lot of data in each, then you'll use more memory than you should because without an explicit logout or other action that ends the session when it is no longer needed, it will take 90-120 minutes to free up that memory that's not being used.

But all of that is only a problem if you store a lot of data in the session which is in general a bad idea, since even 30 minutes is a long time to wait to reclaim unused session data. Often data that is stored in the session causes data staleness issues, e.g. storing domain class instances means that they're detached from their original Hibernate session and must be reattached. But that just reloads the instance from the database using the instance's id, so storing the id would have been sufficient. Usually you'll find that there are much more efficient caches than the HTTP session.